# Outlook macro to interrupt a reply-all?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is it possible to create an outlook macro such that when a user presses "Reply to All", there is a prompt saying something like "Your message will be sent to the following recipients: x,y,z.  Are you sure? Y/N".  The key question here is if there is even a hook available to interrupt the action at all.

Note that I am not looking to disable it or to buy an add-in.

Comment: If that came default in Outlook, imagine all the savings in Inbox flooding!

Comment: Is it that you don't want to _use_ an add-in, or just don't want to use one you have to pay for?

Comment: It's the cost.  I'm looking for a solution that can be deployed to around 100 machines.

Comment: @digitxp You can [disable reply all](https://www.technipages.com/outlook-disable-reply-to-all-email-recipients) or install the [NoReplay add-on](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52515) to disable the feature on selected emails

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** I'm working on 2007, but I think the code should transfer OK.

You can add an event handler via VBA to pick up the `ReplyAll` event. Something like the following:

```
Dim WithEvents insp As Outlook.Inspectors
Dim WithEvents mailItem As Outlook.MailItem

' This is called on Outlook startup
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set insp = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

' This is called when a new Inspector is created. You use it to pick up on a new mail item event
Private Sub insp_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If Inspector.CurrentItem.Size = 0 And Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
       Set mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem
    End If
End Sub

' Called when you press ReplyAll
Private Sub mailItem_ReplyAll(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim msg As String
    Dim result As Integer
    msg = "Do you really want to reply to all?"
    result = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo, "Reply All Check")
    If result = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There is a note in StackOverflow that someone found a problem with the `Inspector.CurrentItem.Size = 0` test and had to remove it. I don't know whether that is a problem in OL2007 or later. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278814/vba-macro-customize-reply-button