# Outlook macro to confirm reply or reply all when sending

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, reply

I often mistakenly select the *Reply* option when there are many people involving in the talk and I actually want to reply to all of them. Are there any ways to check this before sending the email?

Answer (score 0):

You can interrupt reply in a similar manner as described [in this question](https://superuser.com/q/327614/241386)

[Insert a new module like this](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/how-to-use-outlooks-vba-editor/) and then in the `ThisOutlookSession` module paste the below code

```vb
Dim WithEvents insp As Outlook.Inspectors
Dim WithEvents mailItem As Outlook.MailItem

' This is called on Outlook startup
Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set insp = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

' This is called when a new Inspector is created. 
Private Sub insp_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
       Set mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem
    End If
End Sub

' Called when you press Reply
Private Sub mailItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim msg As String
    Dim result As Integer
    If myMailItem.Recipients.count > 1 Then
        msg = "Do you really want to reply to one?"
        result = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo, "Reply Check")
        If result = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```